# Unexpected Result SQL ORDER BY

Tags: sql, db2

I have a scenario that I dont know how to get the correct results due to my lack of knowledge with SQL and need assistance.

I understand what the ORDER BY command does; I just dont know how to manipulate the data returned from the query to keep the data in the order I need it to be in.

Below is the SQL String:

```
SELECT cfcif# AS "CIF Number",cfna1 AS "Customer Name" FROM cncttp08.jhadat842.cfmast cfmast WHERE cfcif#='T000714'
UNION
SELECT cfcif# AS "CIF Number",cfna1 AS "Customer Name" FROM cncttp08.jhadat842.cfmast cfmast WHERE cfcif#='T000713'
UNION
SELECT cfcif# AS "CIF Number",cfna1 AS "Customer Name" FROM cncttp08.jhadat842.cfmast cfmast WHERE cfcif#='T000715'
ORDER BY "CIF Number"
```

As you can see The "CIF Numbers" are out of order, which is the way they need to be and with the ORDER BY the data is ordered by the CIF#, but I need the data to actually be out of order.

Below is how the current string returns the data:

```
T000713 | ROGER RABBITT                          
T000714 | JESSICA RABBIT                         
T000715 | JAMES KIRK
```

Below is how I need the data returned:

```
T000714 | JESSICA RABBITT
T000713 | ROGER RABBITT
T000715 | JAMES KIRK
```

When I remove the ORDER BY the result returned is this:

```
T000714 | JAMES KIRK
T000713 | JESSICA RABBITT
T000715 | ROGER RABBITT
```

Comment: The name/number combinations change without the `ORDER BY`? That seems unlikely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you use UNION. You can do it like this:

```
SELECT 
  cfcif# AS "CIF Number",
  cfna1 AS "Customer Name" 
  FROM cncttp08.jhadat842.cfmast cfmast 
  WHERE cfcif# IN ('T000714', 'T000713', 'T000715')
ORDER BY
  CASE cfcif# 
    WHEN 'T000714' THEN 1
    WHEN 'T000713' THEN 2
    WHEN 'T000715' THEN 3
  END
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is exactly what i was needing and a great learning tool for me to use as I am still really new to SQL and its functionality.  Much appreciated!.

Answer (score 0):

Simple!

Remove quotes from the order by clause. It should work. Your code should be like below.

```
`SELECT cfcif# AS "CIF Number",cfna1 AS "Customer Name" FROM 
 cncttp08.jhadat842.cfmast cfmast WHERE cfcif#='T000714'
 UNION
 SELECT cfcif# AS "CIF Number",cfna1 AS "Customer Name" FROM 
 cncttp08.jhadat842.cfmast cfmast WHERE cfcif#='T000713'
 UNION
 SELECT cfcif# AS "CIF Number",cfna1 AS "Customer Name" FROM 
 cncttp08.jhadat842.cfmast cfmast WHERE cfcif#='T000715'
 ORDER BY CIF Number`
```

Comment: That won't work.  If a column name is mixed case, or has a space in it, you will need to put it in double quotes

Comment: agreed with your comment.